# Update libs with cocoapods break build

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking, magicalrecord

I'm having problems building since try update some frameworks. I use pod update and after that can't build my project. The error message is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
      objc-class-ref in Utils.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CSNotificationView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ...+Utils.o
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ...
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIDictionaryBuilder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IQKeyboardManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in .....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LTHPasscodeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in .....
      objc-class-ref in LTHPasscodeViewController+Config.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_LTHPasscodeViewController_$_Config in LTHPasscodeViewController+Config.o
      objc-class-ref in ...
      objc-class-ref in ....
      objc-class-ref in ....
      objc-class-ref in ....
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MagicalRecord", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in .....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PCPieChart", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PCPieComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ....
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UICKeyChainStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in .....
  "_kGAIScreenName", referenced from:
      +[.... trackWithName:] in ....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried remove these frameworks and install manually but unsuccessful, compatibility is ok but i don't know what happening.Remove derived data didn't work too ... Someone can help me?

Edit: podfile

```
    platform:ios, '7.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.0'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.13'
pod 'iOSPlot', '~> 1.0.1'
pod 'CSNotificationView', '~> 0.5.4'
pod 'MACircleProgressIndicator', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'LTHPasscodeViewController', '~> 3.7.1'
pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 3.3.4'
pod 'Rollbar'
pod 'UICKeyChainStore', '~> 2.0.6'

target 'xxxxx' do
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.2'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 4.3'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your Podfile please?

Comment: @SvenDriemecker Edit answer with podfile

Comment: If that is your full Podfile, try encapsulating the main part into target 'ABC' do ... end. There is only a explicit target part for your UnitTest-Target. Also, if you've added any new pods since it last worked, be sure to run pod install and not just pod update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Podfile should look like this, with an explicit target definition and *inherited search_paths* set for your unittest-target (see [official ref](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)):

```
target ABC do
    platform:ios, '7.0'

    inhibit_all_warnings!

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.0'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.13'
    pod 'iOSPlot', '~> 1.0.1'
    pod 'CSNotificationView', '~> 0.5.4'
    pod 'MACircleProgressIndicator', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'LTHPasscodeViewController', '~> 3.7.1'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 3.3.4'
    pod 'Rollbar'
    pod 'UICKeyChainStore', '~> 2.0.6'

    target 'xxxxx' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.2'
        pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 4.3'
    end
end
```

Be sure to run `pod install` and not just `pod update` if you want to integrate any new pod into your project (see [why](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html)).

Your last option is to start pod integration from sratch:

1. completely remove pods from your project `pod deintegrate`
2. reintegrate pods with `pod install`